# How to get all the child elements of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy all the child elements of parent div into the text box using jquery. 
I tried to find the solution over stackoverflow and google, but did not find any solution. Please help, i will be very greatful. Thanks in advance

```
 <div id="hello">
  <div class="sub1">Hello how are you</div>
   <div class="sub2">Hello how are you</div>
    <div class="sub3">Hello how are you</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to copy all the children elements in the text

The output should come like this:

```
   <input type="hidden" value="<div class="sub1">Hello how are you</div><div class="sub2">Hello how are you</div><div class="sub3">Hello how are you</div></div>"   id="textbox">
```

Comment: Use `$('#hello').html()`

Comment: But It will be broken with `"` quote in side `Value` attribute of hidden field.

Comment: there seems an extra `</div>` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `html()` to get the all the dom and text value

```
$("#textbox").val($("#hello").html());
```

Comment: *Sigh*, sure. Please read the question again. This does not answer it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi sorry i wrongly understand .now i changed the post

Comment: Nice, thank you for your efforts. This makes your answer the best one posted so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alert($("#hello").html())

$('input:hidden').val($("#hello").html())
```

Comment: @merlin, yes. This is a no-research question, answering it means some of us will consider the answer with a harsher point of view. In addition, answers containing `Try this` and code without further explanation are starting to become the norm here although they're not useful, we do not want to encourage this. Finally, `input:hidden` does not only match `<input type="hidden">` elements, this code may clobber the values of other `<input>` elements that are not shown.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Understood.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this you can do as below:

```
var values=$('#hello').html();
$('#textbox').val(values); // textbox is the id of hidden field you specified
```